# Workflow implementation

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Where I can find example for workflow implementation? Actually we are not able to attach workflow definition to a Page or Component. We have created new Workflow definition for Page and Component when we open a page and go to Workflow tab it is showing "Approval Status: Undefined"

We recently upgraded from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1, we have executed the step mentioned in Upgrade manual "Upgrading existing default Workflow Process
Definitions"

As per my understanding under workflow tab we should be able to select workflow definition to be followed by Page or Component

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Pages, Workflow Processes are attached to Structure Groups (you'll be able to select the Process Definition in the Workflow Tab of the Structure Group).  When attached to a SG, any page that you create or edit in that SG will start the workflow for that item.  Note that Structure Group's do not inherit this setting, so every SG you'll have to attach the process to.

For Components, Workflow Processes are attached to the Schema (you'll be able to select the Process Definition in the Workflow Tab of the Schema).  When a Schema has a workflow, any Component that is created or edited using that schema will be put into a workflow.

Note that child Publications won't automatically have Components and Pages kick into workflow.  For example, if your schemas with attached Process Definitions are at the 010 level, and your components are at the 020 level, you'll have to go to the Workflow Tab in the Publication properties of your 020 level and make sure to check "Enable Workflow Process Associations in Shared Schemas and Structure Groups".

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Alex, really helpful info. I will implement it now, and will get back if any issues.